# SVN under Cygwin: target folder resolves wrong

Tags: svn, windows-7, cygwin

I'm using the default Cygwin installation on a Windows 7 machine.
When I try to do a checkout, the svn client resolves the target path incorrectly.

For example, the command:

```
svn checkout http://subversion:81/svn/project/trunk "/cygdrive/c/Users/LeMe/Desktop/project test"
```

will start tracing stuff like

```
Checking out test

A    C:\cygdrive\c\Users\LeMe\Desktop\project test\src\
A    C:\cygdrive\c\Users\LeMe\Desktop\project test\src\com
...
```

and will checkout the folder to the exact folder C:\cygdrive\c\Users\LeMe\Desktop\project test\ on my hard drive, instead of following the normal pointer to c in cygwin.

Any ideas how to let the svn client resolve the target path correctly?
I've already tried to use quotes, use no spaces, even created a shortcut in the folder C:\cygdrive\ named c point to c:. But no result so far.

Maybe useful:

```
$ which svn
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/CollabNet/Subversion Client/svn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a Windows Subversion install in Cygwin. Run the [Cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com/install.html), install the "svn" package, and everything should start working properly.

Do beware line-ending issues if you're planning on using both a Windows Subversion client and the Cygwin one. In particular, expect any files that have `svn:eol-style` set to `native` to cause issues. It'll all work, but you'll need to run things through `unix2dos` and/or `dos2unix` on occasion when the system complains at you or reports files have changed when they haven't.

Answer (score 3):

Your path is finding a windows svn binary before it finds the cygwin svn binary.

The windows binary doesn't know anything about the cygwin /cygdrive link, so it does exactly what you ask it to do and checks out to a new folder.

You probably need to modify your path environmental variable so that the cygwin svn binary is the first one that is located, if it is indeed installed.

Comment: ... or don't use SVN under cygwin

Comment: Cygwin should handle the paths for you; before passing the path to the Windows svn binary, it should convert it into a Windows path.

Comment: …but apparently it doesn't. Oh well.